# Как наложить одно изображение на другое в opencv 3?

Tags: c++, opencv

Имеются два изображения, как наложить одно изображение на другое в opencv 3? C++

Answer (score 0):

Если я вас правильно понял, та вам нужна функция `blendLinear`. Для ее использования придется немножко повозиться, так как она принимает 5 аргументов:

- первое трехканальное изображение
- второе трехканальное
- альфа (чаще всего требуется 1 - beta)
- бета (четвертый канал второго изображения)
- выходное изображение

При этом альфа и бета - однокональные и имеют тип CV_32F. Если вам нужен ещё и четвертый канал (выходной), то это вычисляется отдельно по формуле:

```
beta + alpha(1 - beta)
```